# The arial narrow font is serif or sans serif?

Tags: html, fonts

I am using a arial narrow font for site menu.
It is said that you should not use serif font for menu.
I just wanted to know that arial narrow font is serif or sans serif?

Comment: I was in real hurry and I referred few articles but dint get clear idea about it, so asked on SO as a quicker way. One of the link I opened was actually malicious site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sans-serif is basically French for 'Without serifs".

Serifs are artistic lines that are used by font designers to make their fonts look different, but shouldn't detract from the letter shapes.

If you look at a T in a sans-serif font, you would generally see a vertical line with a horizontal line.  In a serif font, there may be short lines dangling from either end of the horizontal line.  These are the serifs.

On my Windows system, Arial is sans-serif, whilst Times New Roman is serif.

Answer (score 1):

Arial Narrow is sans-serif. Read more about serif and sans-serif [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif).